# How do I update element in array if same field exists leave else update in collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In my task collection, I have a users field. While updating, I need to check if the same userid is in users.assigned, I need to leave or if a different userid is assigned, I need to push that record.

```
db.tasks.find({
"_id" : ObjectId("60ddd690c6d9014f7a8c9af2")
"createdDate" : ISODate("2021-07-01T14:50:51Z"),
"modifiedDate" : ISODate("2021-07-01T14:50:51Z"),
"users" : {
        "assigned" : [
            {"userid" : ObjectId("5d9fd8613d598088d2ea5e2b"),
                "team" : "APPLICATIONS DEVELOPMENT"},           
        ],
})
```

I need to push if this userid is not on my list.

```
{"userid" : ObjectId("5de8ad4263d21b900e1be386"),
  "team" : "APPLICATIONS DEVELOPMENT"},
```

My output should be like

```
"users" : {
        "assigned" : [
            {"userid" : ObjectId("5d9fd8613d598088d2ea5e2b"),
                "team" : "APPLICATIONS DEVELOPMENT"},
            {"userid" : ObjectId("5de8ad4263d21b900e1be386"),
                "team" : "APPLICATIONS DEVELOPMENT"},
        ],
}
```

I tried  using findByIdAndUpdate, I don't know how exactly I should form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- check not equal to condition for `userid`
- `$push` element in `assigned` array

```
await YourSchemaModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  {
    "users.assigned.userid": {
      $ne: ObjectId("5de8ad4263d21b900e1be386")
    }
  },
  {
    $push: {
      "users.assigned": {
        "userid": ObjectId("5de8ad4263d21b900e1be386"),
        "team": "APPLICATIONS DEVELOPMENT"
      }
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dDxMTySejNK)